# If $f$ is K-Lipschitz continuous, then for a set $A$, is $f(A) \subset A$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

While solving a problem, I noticed that I could solve it faster if the statement

> $f$ is $K$-Lipschitz continuous, then for a set $A$, is $f(A) \subset A$

was true, I could solve it much more easily. The problem is that I am unsure if this is true, so far the examples of functions that are $K$-Lipschitz continuous had this property. So my questions is- is this correct? And if so, any hints for a proof?

Comment: Lipschitz functions need not map between the same spaces, let alone have their ranges inside their domains.

Comment: Suppose the range of $f$ is the same as the domain of $f$. Even so, you could come up with an example like $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ with $f(x) = 1 + \frac x 2$, which is Lipschitz with $K = \frac 1 2$. Now then, take $A = (-\frac 1 2, \frac 1 2)$...